# PONG XI Platinum Edition

Tags: c++, beginner, game, sfml, pong

This is my first game.

This header defines the constants:

Constants.h:

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H_INCLUDED
#define CONSTANTS_H_INCLUDED

#define WIN_WIDTH 800
#define WIN_HEIGHT 600

#define BALL_SPEED_X 4
#define BALL_SPEED_MAX_Y 4

#define BAR_FROM_BORDERS 40
#define BAR_SPEED 7

#define MAX_FPS 60



#endif // CONSTANTS_H_INCLUDED
```

This is the main class:

PSprite.h:

```
#ifndef PSPRITE_H
#define PSPRITE_H

/**
    *This class inherits the class
    *Sprite, and defines some
    *attributes to keep track of
    *a Sprite's geometry.
*/

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "CollisionManager.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class PSprite : public sf::Sprite
{
    public:
        PSprite(std::string&, const float& x, const float& y);

        const float& getDirectionX();
        const float& getDirectionY();
        const sf::Vector2f& getLowerRight();                    //Getters
        const float& getWidth();
        const float& getHeight();

        void setPosition(float,float);
        void setDirectionX(const float&);
        void setDirectionY(const float&);                       //Setters
        void setLowerRight();

        bool strictlyHigherThan(PSprite&);
        bool strictlyLowerThan(PSprite&);
        bool strictlyLeftOf(PSprite&);                          //Relative position verification
        bool strictlyRightOf(PSprite&);


        PSprite* nextMove();                                    //Returns a ptr on the sprite after its next movement

    protected:
        sf::Texture texture;                      //The sprite's texture
        CollisionManager collision;               //The Collision manager
        float directionX;                         //The direction on X axis
        float directionY;                         //The direction on Y axis
        float width;                              //The sprite's width
        float height;                             //The Sprite's height
        sf::Vector2f lowerRight;                  //Lower right corner's coordinates

};

#endif // PSPRITE_H
```

PSprite.cpp:

```
#include "PSprite.h"
#include <string>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

PSprite::PSprite(std::string& filename,const float& x, const float& y)
{
    texture.loadFromFile(filename);                 //Loading the texture

    setTexture(texture);                            //Setting the sprite
    setPosition(x,y);

    width=texture.getSize().x;                      //Setting width and height
    height=texture.getSize().y;

    //setLowerRight();                                //Setting the lower right corner

    directionX=0;                                   //Setting the directions to default values
    directionY=0;
}

const float& PSprite::getDirectionX()
{
    return directionX;
}

const float& PSprite::getDirectionY()
{
    return directionY;
}

const Vector2f& PSprite::getLowerRight()
{
    return lowerRight;
}

const float& PSprite::getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

const float& PSprite::getHeight()
{
    return height;
}


void PSprite::setPosition(float x,float y)
{
    Sprite::setPosition(x,y);
    setLowerRight();                    //We set the lower right corner each time we change the position
}
void PSprite::setDirectionX(const float& dirX)
{
    directionX=dirX;
}

void PSprite::setDirectionY(const float& dirY)
{
    directionY=dirY;
}

void PSprite::setLowerRight()
{
    lowerRight.x=getPosition().x+width;
    lowerRight.y=getPosition().y+height;
}


bool PSprite::strictlyHigherThan(PSprite& spr)
{
    return lowerRight.y<spr.getPosition().y;            //If the lowest point of this is higher than spr's highest
}

bool PSprite::strictlyLowerThan(PSprite& spr)
{
    return spr.strictlyHigherThan(*this);               //If spr is strictly higher than this
}

bool PSprite::strictlyLeftOf(PSprite& spr)
{
    return lowerRight.x<spr.getPosition().x;            //If the rightest point of this is on spr's leftest left
}

bool PSprite::strictlyRightOf(PSprite& spr)
{
    return spr.strictlyLeftOf(*this);                   //If spr is strictly on the left of this
}


PSprite* PSprite::nextMove()                            //Returns a pointer on this' position after its next move
{
    PSprite *next=new PSprite(*this);

    next->setPosition(getPosition().x+directionX,getPosition().y+directionY);

    return next;
}
```

This class manages collisions:

CollisionManager.h:

```
#ifndef COLLISIONMANAGER_H
#define COLLISIONMANAGER_H


/**
  *Class that manages collisions (!)
  *between 2 PSprites or a PSprite
  *and the screen borders
*/

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Constants.h"
class PSprite;

class CollisionManager
{
    public:
        CollisionManager();

        bool CollBorderV(PSprite&);             //Managing collision between a PSprite and the vertical borders of the screen
        bool CollBorderH(PSprite&);             //Managing collision between a PSprite and the horizontal borders of the screen

        bool Coll2PSprite(PSprite&,PSprite&);   //Managing the collision between two PSprites

};

#endif // COLLISIONMANAGER_H
```

CollisionManager.cpp:

```
#include "CollisionManager.h"
#include "Ball.h"
#include "PSprite.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;

CollisionManager::CollisionManager()
{

}


bool CollisionManager::Coll2PSprite(PSprite& spr1, PSprite& spr2)       //Managing the collision between two PSprites
{
    PSprite *nxt=spr1.nextMove();

    if(nxt->strictlyHigherThan(spr2) || nxt->strictlyLowerThan(spr2) || nxt->strictlyLeftOf(spr2) || nxt->strictlyRightOf(spr2))    //If they don't collide after spr1's next move
    {
        delete nxt;
        return 0;
    }

    if(spr1.strictlyHigherThan(spr2))
    {
        spr1.setPosition(spr1.getPosition().x,spr2.getPosition().y-spr1.getHeight());
        //spr1.setLowerRight();
    }

    else if(spr1.strictlyLowerThan(spr2))
    {
        spr1.setPosition(spr1.getPosition().x,spr2.getLowerRight().y);
        //spr1.setLowerRight();
    }

    if(spr1.strictlyLeftOf(spr2))
    {
        spr1.setPosition(spr2.getPosition().x-spr1.getWidth(),spr1.getPosition().y);
        //spr1.setLowerRight();
    }

    else if(spr1.strictlyRightOf(spr2))
    {
        spr1.setPosition(spr2.getLowerRight().x,spr1.getPosition().y);
        //spr1.setLowerRight();
    }

    delete nxt;
    return 1;
}

bool CollisionManager::CollBorderH(PSprite& spr)
{
    PSprite *nxt=spr.nextMove();

    if(nxt->getPosition().y>0 && nxt->getLowerRight().y<WIN_HEIGHT)       //If there is no collision
    {
        delete nxt;
        return 0;
    }

    if(nxt->getPosition().y<0)                                              //If there is a collision with the upper border
    {
        spr.setPosition(spr.getPosition().x,0);
        //spr.setLowerRight();
    }

    else if(nxt->getLowerRight().y>WIN_HEIGHT)                            //If there is a collision with the lower border
    {
        spr.setPosition(spr.getPosition().x,WIN_HEIGHT-spr.getHeight());
        //spr.setLowerRight();
    }

    delete nxt;
    return 1;
}

bool CollisionManager::CollBorderV(PSprite& spr)        //Manages collisions between a PSPrite and vertical borders
{
    PSprite *nxt=spr.nextMove();

    if(nxt->getPosition().x>0 && nxt->getLowerRight().x<WIN_WIDTH)
    {
        delete nxt;
        return 0;
    }

    if(nxt->getPosition().x<0)
    {
        spr.setPosition(0,spr.getPosition().y);
    }

    else if(nxt->getLowerRight().x>WIN_WIDTH)
    {
        spr.setPosition(WIN_WIDTH-spr.getWidth(),spr.getPosition().y);
    }

    delete nxt;
    return 1;
}
```

This is the ball's class:

Ball.h:

```
#ifndef BALL_H_INCLUDED
#define BALL_H_INCLUDED


/**
  *This class inherits from the class
  *PSprite and defines the method motion
  *that indicates how the Ball moves
*/

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include "Bar.h"
#include "CollisionManager.h"
#include "PSprite.h"

class Ball:public PSprite
{
    public:
        Ball(std::string,float,float);

        void motion(std::vector<PSprite*>,bool&);
};

#endif // BALL_H_INCLUDED
```

Ball.cpp:

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Constants.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

Ball::Ball(string filename,float x, float y):PSprite(filename,x,y)
{

}

void Ball::motion(vector<PSprite*> sprites,bool& paused)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sprites.size();i++)                           //sprites contains pointers on all the sprites on screen, in this case the 2 bars
    {
        if(collision.Coll2PSprite(*this,*sprites[i]))           //If a ball collides with a PSprite it changes directionX
        {
            directionX*=-1;
            directionY=rand()%BALL_SPEED_MAX_Y;
        }
    }

    if(collision.CollBorderH(*this))                //If a ball collides with a horizontal border it changes directionY
    {
        directionY=directionY*-1;
    }

    move(directionX,directionY);                    //Making the next movement


    if(collision.CollBorderV(*this))                //If the ball collides with a vertical border we reset the game
    {
        setPosition(WIN_WIDTH/2,WIN_HEIGHT/2);
        directionY=0;

        sprites[0]->setPosition(WIN_WIDTH-BAR_FROM_BORDERS,WIN_HEIGHT/2);
        sprites[0]->setLowerRight();

        sprites[1]->setPosition(BAR_FROM_BORDERS,WIN_HEIGHT/2);
        sprites[1]->setLowerRight();

        paused=1;
    }

    setLowerRight();
}
```

This is the bars' class:

Bar.h:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

/**
   * This class Bar inherits from the class
   * PSprite and defines the method motion
   * which indicates how the bars move.
*/

#include <string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "CollisionManager.h"
#include "PSprite.h"

class Bar:public PSprite
{
    public:
        Bar(std::string,float,float);
        void motion();
};

#endif // BAR_H
```

Bar.cpp:

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include "PSprite.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

Bar::Bar(string filename,float x,float y):PSprite(filename,x,y)
{


}

void Bar::motion()
{
    if(!collision.CollBorderH(*this))       //If a bar collides with a horizontal border it can't move in its direction
    {
        move(0,directionY);
        setLowerRight();
        directionY=0;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Ball.h"
#include "Bar.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Constants.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT), "Pong XI: Tokyo Drift");       // Create the main window

    Ball ball("Sprites/ball.png",WIN_WIDTH/2,WIN_HEIGHT/2);             //Setting the ball
    ball.setDirectionX(BALL_SPEED_X);

    Bar blu("Sprites/bluBar.png",WIN_WIDTH-BAR_FROM_BORDERS,WIN_HEIGHT/2);      //Setting the bars
    Bar red("Sprites/redBar.png",BAR_FROM_BORDERS,WIN_HEIGHT/2);

    vector<PSprite*> bars;                                          //Creating the vector and adding the two bars to it
    bars.push_back(&blu);
    bars.push_back(&red);

    bool paused=1;

    bool z=0;
    bool s=0;
    bool up=0;
    bool down=0;

    Texture background;
    background.loadFromFile("Sprites/background.png");        //Setting the background
    Sprite sp_bg;
    sp_bg.setTexture(background);

    app.setFramerateLimit(MAX_FPS);
    app.setVerticalSyncEnabled(1);

    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;        // Process events
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)                  // Event's type
            {
                case Event::Closed :                // Close button on the window
                    app.close();
                break;

                case Event::KeyPressed :            // Event key pressed
                {
                    switch (event.key.code)             // The pressed key
                    {
                        case Keyboard::Escape :             // Escape
                            app.close();
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Up:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                up=1;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Down:                //To manage simultaneous key pressing we set booleans
                            if(!paused)                     //linked to the pressed buttons and later make movements
                            {                               //based on their values
                                down=1;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Z:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                z=1;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::S:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                s=1;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Space:
                            paused=!paused;
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;

                case Event::KeyReleased:
                {
                    switch (event.key.code)             // The released key
                    {
                        case Keyboard::Up:
                            if(!paused)                 //Stopping the movement when the keys are released
                            {
                                up=0;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Down:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                down=0;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::Z:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                z=0;
                            }
                        break;

                        case Keyboard::S:
                            if(!paused)
                            {
                                s=0;
                            }
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;

                default :
                break;
            }
        }

        if(paused)
        {
            z=0;                    //Stopping the movements if the game is paused
            s=0;
            up=0;
            down=0;
        }

        if(z)                               //Verifying the booleans to make movements
        {
            red.setDirectionY(-BAR_SPEED);
            red.motion();
        }

        if(s)
        {
            red.setDirectionY(BAR_SPEED);
            red.motion();
        }

        if(up)
        {
            blu.setDirectionY(-BAR_SPEED);
            blu.motion();
        }

        if(down)
        {
            blu.setDirectionY(BAR_SPEED);
            blu.motion();
        }

        if(!paused)
        {
            ball.motion(bars,paused);
        }

        app.clear();        // Clear screen


        app.draw(sp_bg);
        app.draw(ball);     // Draw the sprite
        app.draw(blu);
        app.draw(red);


        app.display();      // Update the window

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Prefer to make the constants proper (i.e., type-safe) constants using `const` or `constexpr` instead of a C-style macro. This increases maintainability and protects from unintended errors.
2. In PSprite (and in general), make *every* member function const if it is not modifying the state of the object. Case in point are your getters.
3. Use the initialization list in a constructor (see e.g., PSprite). So prefer to write along the lines of:

   ```
   PSprite::PSprite(std::string& filename, const float& x, const float& y)
      : directionX(0), directionY(0)
   {
      texture.loadFromFile(filename);                 //Loading the texture

      setTexture(texture);                            //Setting the sprite
      setPosition(x, y);

      width = texture.getSize().x;                      //Setting width and height
      height = texture.getSize().y;
   }
   ```

Perhaps there is room for additional members to be initialized in the initialization list as well.

Also, I find your comments too verbose. They should specify more "why" and not "what". For example, if you set two member variables to zero in a constructor, it is perfectly clear they are initialized to sensible default values without an explicit comment.

4. What is the purpose of CollisionManager as a stateless class? It seems to me that you might as well make the collision detection functionality into free (non-member) functions and get rid of the unnecessary class.
5. In the constructor of Bar, pass the string as const-ref instead of by-value. Cheap-to-copy objects (like ints and floats) are typically passed by-value.
6. Avoid using "naked pointers" to avoid leaking memory. Have a look at [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and others for doing this properly and safely.